# How to configure Gizmo5 on Trixbox/Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, trixbox, softphone

Does anyone know how to configure Gizmo5 for use on an Asterisk PBX? Specifically [Trixbox](http://www.trixbox.com/) if possible.

For the life of me I just can't get [this](http://support.gizmo5.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=179) to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks as if you're trying to use Gizmo's Dual Login feature, which is a little different from just hooking up your Gizmo account to asterisk. From what I can see, Dual Login allows you to login to both Gizmo and another SIP provider/PBX at the same time.

Where are you running into a problem?

First question: are you using trixbox CE or trixbox Pro?

Second: can you register the Gizmo softphone to your PBX or not?

When I just tried, it registered instantly to my preconfigured softphone account. 
I entered:

- Server, The server's hostname
- Account name, the context for the peer you're
  trying to register to. You're going
  to need one extension for every user.
  In sip.conf or one of the sip_*.conf
  files, this would be the [peer] name
  for the extension.
- Password, shown in sip.conf as "secret=****"

Can we get the asterisk logs when you try to register using Gizmo? Make sure you've enabled verbose logging in /etc/asterisk/logging.conf first.

One thing I noticed is that the registration attempt actually comes from Gizmo's SIP server, not my client's IP address. Could you be blocking based on IP?

Third: can you register other softphones successfully?

Fourth: if it's not registration, are you having problems with call routing, and if so, which way?

Comment: Your comment about the registrations coming from Gizmo's SIP server helped me troubleshoot the issue. Trixbox wasn't correctly updating the public IP. Thanks!